# Problem with sound and headphones

Tags: audio, headphones

I have this weird problem where all sounds while headphones are plugged in my phone is stuck in the background, but without the headphones the sound works fine. I am utterly clueless on how to fix this so any help is appreciated.

Comment: The jack is as clean as it can be, not even a single speck of dirt or lint in it. The sound is stuck in the background as in the sound is muffled but still hearable like it's coming from a distance.

Comment: Haven't been around to be able to answer, but no that didn't help. No matter how loud the audio is it's still muffled.

Comment: Yeah turns out the headphones were only made to be used on a pc or laptop. Got new ones for phones specifically and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out headphones were made for desktop use only. The darn manual had not mentioned this at all.